# Calculate a limit changing the variable

Tags: calculus

I have the following limit to calculate:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{x}$$

I have to use: $$y=\frac{1}{x}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{e^{-\frac1x}}{x}=\lim_{y\to +\infty}ye^{-y}=\lim_{y\to +\infty}\frac{y}{e^y}\overset{\frac{\infty}{\infty}}{=}\lim_{y\to +\infty}\frac{(y)'}{(e^y)'}=\lim_{y\to +\infty}\frac{1}{e^y}=0$$ by L'Hopital's rule.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim _{ x\rightarrow { 0 }^{ + } }{ \frac { { e }^{ \frac { -1 }{ x }  } }{ x }  } \\ =\lim _{ y\rightarrow \infty  }{ { ye }^{ -y } } \\ =0$$

In the second last step I used [L'Hospital's Rule](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LHospitalsRule.html)